# Loop Nesting List RxJava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I Have a List of Object A, and in every A I have a list of Object B.

here is what I want to do:

while looping over `List<A>` using RxJava I want to be able to loop the inner list and do some filtering on the `List<B>` and at the end, I would like to add the filtered `List<B>` to the original parent object of `List<A>`.

is this operation possible without breaking the chain?

something like this example :

```
class A {
        int mAId;
        List<B> mBList;
    }

    class B{
        int mId;
    }

    public void loop(List<A> list){
        Observable.fromIterable(list)
                .flatMapIterable(objs-> objs.mBList)
                .filter("filtering each b")
                .toList()
                .map("add back the list of b to the right a")
                .subscribe()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this problem:

```
class A(val filterable: Boolean = random.nextBoolean())

class B(val name: String = random.nextInt().toString(), val listOfA: List<A> = listOf(A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A()))

@Test
fun rxTest() {
    Observable.fromIterable(listOf(B(), B(), B(), B(), B(), B(), B()))
            .compose {
                it.publish<B> { publish ->
                    val filteredList = publish.flatMapIterable { it.listOfA }
                            .filter {
                                it.filterable
                            }
                            .toList()
                            .toObservable()
                    Observable.zip<B, List<A>, B>(publish, filteredList, BiFunction<B, List<A>, B> { b, listOfA ->
                        B(b.name, listOfA)
                    })
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

```
    public void loop(List<A> list){
     List<FromObject> innerList;
     list.forEach(e->{
      innerList=e.getInnerList();
      innerList.forEach(in->{
      <apply your filter here>
      <for example>
       if(in.getNumber()>0)
        innerList.remove(in);
      }
     }
    }
```

Wish it would help

Comment: but its not with Rxjava

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve it by nesting the reactive streams:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        Arrays.asList(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),
        Arrays.asList(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
        Arrays.asList(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
);

Observable.fromIterable(listOfLists)
        .flatMap((innerList) -> {
            return Observable.fromIterable(innerList)
                    .filter((value) -> value % 2 == 0)
                    .toList()
                    .toObservable();
        })
        .toList()
        .subscribe(listOfListsFiltered -> {
            for (List<Integer> innerList : listOfListsFiltered) {
                for (Integer value : innerList) {
                    System.out.print(value + ", ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: this way the listoflist object will be lost.
and as I said in the question the filtered inner list has to be added back to the correct parent object with the right id (the object that the inner list has been acquired from).

Answer (score -1):

for future readers or inspiration of a better answer.
There is Another way of doing this

```
public static class A {
        int id;
        List<B> mBList;
    }

    public static class B {
        int id;
    }

    public void test() {

        Observable.just(Arrays.asList(new A(), new A(), new A()))
                .flatMapIterable(a -> a)
                .map(a -> {
                    a.mBList = Observable.fromIterable(a.mBList)
                            .distinct()
                            .toList()
                            .blockingGet();
                    return a;
                });
    }
```